# chai: Cannot read property 'not' of undefined

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I am new to `chai` and `mocha` and I use the sample code for my first test case. Here is my code.

```
var chai = require("chai");
var mocha = require("mocha");
var expect = chai.expect;

describe("Test", function() {
    it("Test", function() {
        expect([1, 2]).to.be.an('array').that.does.not.include(3);
    });
});
```

I run `mocha test.js`

The result is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'not' of undefined
```

What is wrong with me? It seems `.does` return undefined. I remove `.does` and it works correctly. What is the correct usage?

The following code works.

```
expect([1, 2]).to.be.an('array').that.not.include(3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run your code with Chai 4, it works. When I downgrade it to Chai 3 I get the error you get. `does` was added as a no-op assertion in Chai 4.0.0. You are using a version of Chai that predates 4.0.0.

If you check the [releases](http://chaijs.com/releases/) information, you'll find for version 4.0.0, this:

> Add `does` and `but` as new no-op assertion. (Related Issues: #700, #339 PRs: #621, #701)

(You can find the same information in the Github [release](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/releases/tag/4.0.0), with the added benefit that the issue numbers are links to the actual issues.)